# Maxwell equations and continuity equation

Tags: electromagnetism, conservation-laws, maxwell-equations

I want to show the following equation with the maxwell equations:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}W+\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{S} = 0 $$

The problem is that I'm not understanding why I can do the following step:

$$\partial_t W=\partial_t \frac{1}{8\pi}(\vec{E}^2+\vec{B}^2)=\frac{1}{4\pi}(\vec{E}\partial_t\vec{E}+\vec{B}\partial_t\vec{B})$$

Can maybe someone explain it to me?

Comment: Which part of the equation are you struggling with? It looks like straight-forward differentiation to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \vec{E} \cdot \vec{E} \right) 
=\; & 
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \sum_{i=1}^3 E_i^2 \right) 
\\ = & 
\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} E_i^2 
\\ = &
\sum_{i=1}^3 2E_i \frac{\partial}{\partial t}E_i 
\\ = &
 \;2 \vec{E} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \vec{E} 
\end{align}